# User login/registration after filling out form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to have visiting users interact with an input form that ultimately requires a user_id. When a visiting user submits the form, it brings them to a confirmation page. At this point, the user should be able to login or register without losing all the information they entered already. What's the best approach for this?

Comment: will the confirmation page have a similar form on it?

Comment: Kind of. I have it show just text instead of an input field if there are no errors for that field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will have two form submit buttons on the page. A "register" and "login" button. Each of these buttons will be in their own form. I would make hidden fields in each form with the values being the `params[:your_variable]`from the previous page that you want submitted.

If you want forms for them to edit just set the default value to those params as well.